# How to configure a custom Kafka deserializer and get the consumed JSON data using a KafkaListener

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am trying to consume a JSON message using spring kafka. The message which is consumed by the consumer is like this.

```
{
    "EventHeader": {
        "entityName": "Account",
        "changedFields": ["Id", "Name"]
    },
    "NewFields": {
        "Id": "001",
        "Name": "Test Account",
    },
    "OldFields": {}
}
```

So far I have created classes for "EventHeader", "NewFields","OldFields" ,and for "KafkaPayload". And also I have created a custom deserializer to deserialize this JSON payload.Here is my custom deserializer.

```
   public class CustomDeserailizer <T extends Serializable> implements Deserializer<T> {
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    public static final String VALUE_CLASS_NAME_CONFIG = "value.class.name";
    
        @Override
        public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
            Deserializer.super.configure(configs, isKey);
        }
    
        @Override
        public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] objectData) {
            return (objectData == null) ? null : (T) SerializationUtils.deserialize(objectData);
        }
    
        @Override
        public T deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
            return Deserializer.super.deserialize(topic, headers, data);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void close() {
            Deserializer.super.close();
        }
    }
```

I have set the consumer configurations as below.

```
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Bean
    public KafkaConsumer<String, KafkaPayload> consumerFactory(){
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "groupId");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomDeserializer.class);
        return new KafkaConsumer<>(config);
    }
}
```

Now I need to show the consumed message through a  @KafkaListener setting the consumer into ConsumerFactory. But I don't understand how to do that. This is my first time using kafka.So could anyone give me some idea about this?

This is how I am trying to do that.

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaPayload> kafkaListener(){
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

This is my KafkaListener

```
public class ConsumerService {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "Topic", groupId = "sample-group",containerFactory = "kafkaListener")
    public void consume(KafkaPayload kafkaPayload){

        System.out.println("Consumed Message :"+ kafkaPayload);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Spring Boot, just set the value deserializer class name as a property and Boot will automatically wire it into the container factory for your `@KafkaListener`. No need to define your own consumer factory or container factory.

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=com.acme.CustomDeserializer
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer

Comment: When I tried this, I got errors.  

We use constructor injection, but apparently a no-args constructor is required.  However, when I changed my custom deserializer to use field injection, I got an NPE because Spring didn't inject the required bean into the field.

Comment: When configuring using properties, Spring does not manage the deserializer - kafka creates it within the client; hence the need for a no-arg ctor. Alternatively, you can define it as a bean, and inject it into  the consumer factory, either via a constructor, or setter. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#prog-json